# Iterate between specific range of number in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array with two elements [5, 50]. I want this array iterate as [5, 6, 7,......, 49, 50].

I try below code. But not working as my expectation.

```
function All(arr) {
  let newArry = [];
  for(let i = arr[0]; i < arr[1]; i++ ) {
    newArry[i] = newArry.push(i);
  }
  return newArry;
}

console.log(All([5, 50]));
```

Comment: There are only two elements in your array.... you don't have 45 elements in your array.  Can you clarify what it is exactly that you want to do?  Sounds like you just need a `for` loop.

Comment: What do you expect `newArry.push(i)` to return?

Answer (score 2):

Do like this remove  `newArry[i] =`

```js
function All(arr) {
    let newArry = [];
    for(let i = arr[0]; i < arr[1]; i++ ) {
        newArry.push(i);
    }
    return newArry;
}    
console.log(All([5, 50]));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the two values you want to iterate between:

`const [start, end] = [5, 50];`

2. Create a new array of length difference between your two points:

`Array(end - start + 1) // [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

3. Since all the values will be `undefined`, create an iterator object using `Array#keys`: `Array(end - start + 1).keys() // [object Array Iterator]`
4. Spread that into an array:

`[...Array(end - start + 1).keys()] // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]`

5. Map over the values to create your new array:

`[...Array(end - start + 1).keys()].map(i => i + start) // [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]`

...which gives you something like this:

```
const range = (n, m) => [...Array(m - n + 1).keys()].map(i => i + n);

const [start, end] = [5, 50];

console.log(range(start, end)); // [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
```

Or, to maintain the API of the function in your question, like this:

```
const All = (arr) => {
    const [n, m] = arr;
    return [...Array(m - n + 1).keys()].map(i => i + n);
}

console.log(All([5, 50])); // [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
```

Answer (score -1):

The Array.prototype.push method mutates the original array, so reassigning doesn't make sense.
Just do:

```
newArray.push(i);
```